# CMake and SOIL linking

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, clion

I installed SOIL library for my C++ OpenGL project, but i always get

```
undefined reference to `SOIL_load_OGL_texture'
```

As I read from searching, It means that OpenGL is linking before SOIL. I don't know much about CMAKE, but right now my CMAKEFile looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(game)
add_executable(game main.cpp ...(many files))

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(game ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${SOIL} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Comment: Side note: setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` affects only on **followed** executables and libraries. Placing this setting at the end of the `CMakeLists.txt` has no sence.

Comment: Your bug looks like it is here `${SOIL}` how are you setting this? Don't you need a `find_package()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to set `SOIL` to the SOIL library, and add also possibly use `link_directories` to add the path to the SOIL library.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I am complete noob to cmake. I've installed SOIL library through terminal, so I add its header as pre-compiled <SOIL.h>. Do I have to provide a path to it to CMake?

Comment: I don't know where the library is or how it's named, but `link_directories` has a documentation that you should read. `link_directories(${path_to_SOIL})`

Comment: With a missing symbol, the odds are that it's not a header only library!

Comment: I've found library, it's path: /usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a. So, i've tried putting it in target_link_libraries, so it looks like:
target_link_libraries(game ${/usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})

Comment: so SET(SOIL SOIL) before the target_link_libraries, and then link_directories(/usr/local/lib).

Comment: `${/usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a}`, it's not a variable, use them directly `/usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a`